# Two UICollectionViews in One UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two UICollectionViews in one view controller, however my first collection view is conforming to my second collection view's delegate and data source.

The problem is that the category collection view is conforming to the size of the service collection view and it's trying to return five cells.

How do I make my delegate and data source recognize and conform to the two different collection views? Thanks!

[My App Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lkFS.png)

// HomeController

```
private let categoryCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120),    
                                                      collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
private let serviceCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120),
                                                     collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())


    fileprivate func configureUI() {
    
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            
        popularCategoryCardView.addSubview(categoryCollectionView)
        categoryCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        categoryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        categoryCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
        categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
        categoryCollectionView.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.CategoryCell)
            
        categoryCollectionView.anchor(left: popularCategoryCardView.leftAnchor, bottom: popularCategoryCardView.bottomAnchor,
                                      right: popularCategoryCardView.rightAnchor, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 8, paddingRight: 8, height: 120)

        popularServiceCardView.addSubview(serviceCollectionView)
        serviceCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        serviceCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        serviceCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        serviceCollectionView.delegate = self
        serviceCollectionView.dataSource = self
        serviceCollectionView.register(ServiceCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.ServiceCell)
        
        serviceCollectionView.anchor(left: popularServiceCardView.leftAnchor, bottom: popularServiceCardView.bottomAnchor,
                                     right: popularServiceCardView.rightAnchor, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 8, paddingRight: 8, height: 150) 
    
    }
```

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

```
extension HomeController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.categoryCollectionView {
            return jobCategory.count
        } else {
            return 5
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.categoryCollectionView {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.CategoryCell, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
            cell.jobCategory = jobCategory[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.ServiceCell, for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell
            return cell
        }
    }
    
}
```

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
extension HomeController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if collectionView == self.categoryCollectionView {
            return CGSize(width: 160, height: 120)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 140)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It seems like you did what you try to achieve

Comment: Almost, but the category collection view is conforming to the size of the service collection view and it's trying to return five cells

Comment: My category collection view isn't showing five but it's scrolling like there is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the same layout object for multiple collection views:

```
let categoryLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
categoryLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

categoryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = categoryLayout

let serviceLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
serviceLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

serviceCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = serviceLayout
```